# SAS Enterprise Miner Score Node giving Identical Scores

Tags: sas, enterprise-miner

This question relates to the SAS Enterprise Miner product specifically.

I have an Enterprise Miner diagram that seems to work perfectly on training data, I run both an Impute and a Neural Network to get back a perfectly reasonable model. When I inspect the output I can see the individual predictions on the model.
I also have data to score, created using the same queries but where the target variable was null. I attempted to generation a prediction using a score node, but for some reason each and every EM_PREDICTION from Score is Identical, even when I open the dataset and visually check that the input variables are different.

I'm at a loss as to what is causing this or how to debug it, has anyone seen this before?

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfBJA.png)

[Scored view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqAmD.png)

Comment: Could you please add some sample code so we can have a better idea what you are doing?

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Data-Mining/SAS-EM-predicted-probabilities-in-score-data-set-are-all-the/td-p/238332 I've seen this come up. Can you post similar screen shots? Also, SAS support posts on communities and there's less EM users here.

Comment: I've edited to include my diagram and scored data view (I was capped at two links or would include code export from score and train view, though I'm working in EM and not directly re-coding anything not already a configurable node option )